# A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-core, networking, windows-firewall

I uploaded a XML web service to windows server 2019. When I connect to the service from our client project which was built by using angular + ASP.NET core, from another server, I am receiving following error

> "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
> properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
> failed because connected host has failed to respond.
> (xxxx.xxxxxxx.xx.xx:443)"

I want to say that above error message is not returning continuously when connecting to the service. I can take proper response but sometimes I can take the above mention error.

If any one know to sort this out, please let me know.

Comment: Port 443 is HTTPS which uses TLS to establish a secure connection.,  Most likely the error is due to the certificates being used for TLS not working.  TLS the server sends a certificate block containing the names of possible certificates.  The client than looks up the names in the user stores to find a matching certificate.  The error is usually caused by the client not having any of the certificates loaded in the user stores.  Occasionally the error occurs because the certificates encryption mode is either old and no longer supported or the OS is old and doesn't support the newer modes.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. When this issue is happening time,  I log on to the server where the client project is uploaded, whenever I browse any urls in the chrome or IE, they are not working. This is happening for 4-5 minutes and then automatically is getting ok. Even xml service can not browse. What causes to this issue?. Should I need to store proper SSL certificate for client project url?. Currently I used free SSL certificate for it.

Comment: It could be the server is being attacked.  I found something that may be the issue : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/transport-layer-security-tls-connections-might-fail-or-timeout-when-connecting-or-attempting-a-resumption-326bd5b1-52a1-b367-8179-b154e5c01e90

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I go to  Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall and check for Guest or public networks then it shows as "Not connected". I do not know why.... How can I get enabled?. some times it is changing to "Not Connected".

Comment: What type of connection?  Is is ethernet or Wifi?  You may have a bad connection.  I lile test connection by using PING from cmd with large packet sizes  : ping IP -t -l 65500  This command will ping forever and will find intermittent connections.